# Any experience with Reporting Services "Enter Data" datasource type?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

Using VS 2019 just noticed a new data source type in the Reporting Services project. Cant figure out how to use it.

Does anybody have any experience using it?

[image]